# Rendered LocalStorage values being deleted after refresh page

Tags: javascript

I'm rendering some values of LocalStorage on the HTML page. But whenever I refresh the page, the rendered things get deleted even if the data is still stored in the localStorage. I would like the data to not be deleted on render. I have tried doing an if/else statement for this but have not had luck with it. Could anyone help me a way I could make this happen? Thank you!

This is my code:

```
let myLibrary = [];


const addBook = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
    var fields = {
      title: document.getElementById("title").value,
      author: document.getElementById("author").value,
      pages: document.getElementById("pages").value,
      checkbox: document.getElementById("checkbox").value
    };


myLibrary.push(fields)

localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(myLibrary))


const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'))

if (localStorage.getItem('books')) {
document.getElementById('bookList').innerHTML = data.map(item => {
  return `<div>
    <div>Title: ${item.title}</div>
    <div>Author: ${item.author}</div>
    <div>Pages: ${item.pages}</div>
  </div>`
  console.log(data)
})
} else {
items = []
}





}
```

Comment: where `addBook()` is invoked?

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array. You may need to [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array elements into a string. Possible to build a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question?

Comment: It seems like you are providing an array to innerHTML, which should be a string.

Comment: how can you convert it to a string??